# How global declaration of largly sized array works in C?

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables

```
#define N 10000000
int arr[N];

int main(void)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      arr[i]=i+1;
}
```

Why declaring the array globally do not give any compilation error? What is the chance of the availability of contiguous memory of N*4 bytes in the stack? 
Same for declaring the array with `static` keyword.

Comment: Global variables are normally either placed in the `data` or `bss` sections, not on the stack.

Comment: ... and that's because global variables are _global_. Not just visible to one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This image should help. You can see that on the stack we are allocating memory only for local variables and arrays and function calls and pointers.
While the Global variables/ Static are stored on Perm Storage.

Comment: A "normally" would be nice somewhere in your post. Actually, all of this is up to the compiler/linker and not specified anywhere. The C specs just put *requirements* on the storage, not where it needs to be. I have a compiler somewhere that puts global variables to the very bottom of the stack (i.e upwards the stack frame of `main`).

Answer (score 2):

Global, static global, and static variables do not need to be put in the stack.
The stack is for variables who temporarily exists, and who are relative to a function call, the exact opposite of static/global variables who exist as a single and always present in memory entity.

Also, because that is stated in the C specifications, static and/or global variables have a default initialization to zeros. As most (if not all) compilers do not put them in the stack this cost nothing in term of program execution time.

Comment: "because they are not in the stack" – I'd rather say "because that is stated in the C specifications" (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8138702/2564301 for a quote). "The stack", on the other hand, is *not* part of the C specifications: http://stackoverflow.com/a/79936/2564301 (second comment).

Comment: @Rad Lexus Is that better sir?